# How to have Android App communicate with external MySQL db

Tags: mysql, android, database

I am really confused on how to get data in and out of an android app from the internet.

I imagined that I would store information in the mysql db on the server I already have set up. But from what I have read, I would need some type of in-between web service to make queries with data sent from the app.

Can anybody toss me some tips on how to get something like this started.

Or, if you know of a better way, let me know about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get from a MySql server to an Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898823/how-to-get-from-a-mysql-server-to-an-android-app)

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked several times, for example here: [How to get from a MySql server to an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898823/get-data-to-android-app-from-mysql-server).

Bottom line - you don't connect directly. You have something on your server (like RESTful) that you connect with via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method out. I will be using this method for the current project i am working on.

You basically create a php script on a server and use http posts to send the data to the script, read the tutorial linked below for better explanation.

[mysql/android tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)