# android app running on diffrent device can use same databases?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android.i m developing an android app with database.users can insert and retrieve data from database.i just wanna know same app running on two different devices can share same SQLite database.i don’t want to share data outside the application but share data with users using app on different devices.or i have to put my application on third party server...please ans my question.

Comment: you can keep the data in a sever and sync all the data in that, use webservice for sync data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895904/how-to-have-android-app-communicate-with-external-mysql-db

Comment: @sreekanth  ...thanks for answering my question...thank you so much...now i understand i have to deploy my app on server only...cuz if i use SQLite without server database will be created locally  in that particular device ..and it will be limited to only one user it wont share data between users..right??

Comment: @nobalG thanks for sending me a link...really useful ..thanks a lot

Comment: @nobalG  Google app engine will be a good choice for deployment of such database apps..what you think???

Comment: you might want to check out the parse library for an easy way to create a remote db

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a local database, it don't have "sync" options.

You should use a cloud server with a global database (sqlite, mysql...) and comunicate your app with the server.

The most easy way is create a Rest WebService